# Assign function to function field in C

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to assign a function to a variable field, but I get Segmentation fault.
Here is the code:

```
typedef struct node{
    int info;
    struct node *link;
    void* (*make) (int x);
}node;

void* make_node(int x)
{
    node* new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->info = x;
    new_node->link = NULL;
    return new_node;
}

int main(){
  struct node *n;
  n->make = make_node;
  return 0;
}
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: That does not matter. The code is wrong regardless of a compiler.

Answer (score 2):

you need to allocate some space to node on heap or just use a normal variable of the structure instead of a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Your n variable into main() is uninitialised.
The make_node() function will reserve space for a node structure, so why not call it inside main()?
You may try the code below.

```
typedef struct {
    int info;
    struct node *link;
    void* (*make) (int x);
} node;

void *make_node(int x)
{
    node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->info = x;
    new_node->link = NULL;
    return new_node;
}

int main() {
  struct node *n;
  n = make_node(1);

  free (n);
  return 0;
}
```

p.s avoid casting malloc returns

p.s.2 pay attention for the same problem when you'll use struct node *link inside node

p.s.3 remember to free() unused malloc()ed variables.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to assign a value to n.

1. Change the return type of make_node to node*
2. Do n=make_node(x)

And I strongly advise reading [http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0131103628/ref=redir_mdp_mobile](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628)
This would be the best thing you can do now.

Comment: Did you mean that first I have to fill info and link? If you mean that, it doesen't work.

Comment: Right now n references random location. You must assign it to a valid memory address, either on the stack or on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate space for `n` on the stack this way:

```
int main() {
  struct node n;
  n.make = make_node;
  return 0;
}
```

Otherwise you'd have to allocate it on the heap perhaps as a global variable or using `malloc()`.

Comment: You don't want the parentheses after `make_node`, do you?

Answer (score 0):

With the existing infrastructure, you could write:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int            info;
    struct node   *link;
    void        *(*make)(int x);
} node;

void *make_node(int x)
{
    node* new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->info = x;
    new_node->link = NULL;
    new_node->make = make_node;
    return new_node;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct node *n = make_node(1);
    ...use the newly allocated node...
    return 0;
}
```

This allocates the node before you try to write to it. It also fully initializes the node by setting every field to a known value.  If you need a different function pointer for the `make` member, you can adjust afterwards.